# How to get amount of ERC20 tokens sent in tx from tx hash? (Web3.js)

Tags: web3js, erc-20, javascript

I have tx hash and I would like to see how much ERC20 tokens was sent in this transaction.

How can I do this with web3.js?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First search for the txn dict by txn hash, where you can access the bytecode attached to that txn dict. Then you will need the ERC20 ABI in order to decode that bytecode. The functions in the ABI you should be looking for are either transferFrom or transfer, those 2 functions involve transfer of tokens.